# Match an optional + sign at the end of words

Tags: python, regex

I need to leave + sign after using `re.findall` method

```
import re

text = "size+"


text = re.sub(r'\b[0-9]+\b', '__NUMBER__', text)

token_pattern = re.compile(r'(?u)\b\w+\b')

tokens = token_pattern.findall(text)

print(tokens)
```

I am getting `['size']`, I want to get `['size+']`

Answer (score 1):

You may add `\+?` at the end of the pattern:

```
token_pattern = re.compile(r'(?u)\b\w+\b\+?')
```

It will match a whole word and an optional `+` symbol after it.

Note in Python 3 you do not need to use `(?u)` as it is ON by default and `token_pattern = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b\+?')` will work the same.

[Python 3 demo](https://ideone.com/Rl5Plw):

```
import re
text = "size+"
token_pattern = re.compile(r'\b\w+\b\+?')
print(token_pattern.findall(text))
# => ['size+']
```

Comment: @RustemKussaiynov if the solution provided by Wiktor works for you, mark his answer as accepted :) This way others looking at this question will now it has an answer that is valid, and Wiktor will be credited properly for his help